# Android Layout - Prevent layout shrink when Keyboard is hidden

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to prevent layout to resize when keyboard dissapear. When keyboard is visible, the layout is pulled up as expected by adding 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"` to manifest. But when the keyboard is hidden, the layout is adjusted by taking the whole device height.  Is there a way to keep the layout from resizing when the keyboard is hidden.  Or a way to calculate keyboard height and adjust the relativeLayout height by considering the keyboard height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rlAtmFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/thirty_two_dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/thirty_two_dp">

    <WTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEnterYourPin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/thirty_two_dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:text="@string/biometric_please_enter_your_pin"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/nineteen_sp"
        app:WTextView_font="bold" />


    <WTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCardNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvEnterYourPin"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0.14sp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.40"
        android:text="@string/biometric_please_card_number"
        android:textColor="@color/offer_title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fifteen_sp"
        app:WTextView_font="myriadpro_regular" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPinCodeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPin1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_label"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pin_empty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPin2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_label"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pin_empty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPin3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_label"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pin_empty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPin4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_label"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pin_empty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPin5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_label"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pin_empty" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbEnterAtmPin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llPinCodeContainer"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twenty_four_dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvForgotPin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/biometric_forgot_atm_pin_code"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivNavigateToDigitFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_label"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/next_button_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <WLoanEditTextView
        android:id="@+id/edtEnterATMPin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4">

        <requestFocus />
    </WLoanEditTextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`.

Comment: adjustPan won't pull the layout up when activity starts.

Answer (score 0):

I create [KeyboardAnchor](https://gist.github.com/Eventmaker/0a59d24bd9157d3b74b81b782245c3ce) class to handle custom DialogFragments with edittext`s. So, think you can use similar solution for your needs.

Main idea is to listen global layout changes and inner layout changes and calculate bottom points during ones. And after translate views to needed positions.

And there is no default way to handle this.